# Página não popula um Select com os dados da tabela no banco de dados (DJANGO)

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando fazer com que o select "empresas" retorne os valores do banco armazenados na table "company", porém quando na view coloco para retornar o "objects.all() de "company", a página perde todo o javascript e CSS.

HTML QUE DEVE RETORNAR O SELECT

```html
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %} Dashboard {% endblock title %}

<!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block content %}


<div class="container">
    <label><b></b></label>
    <form action="{% url 'update_tool' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="text" id="tool_id" class="form-control" name="tool_id" value="{{tool.id}}" hidden>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="form-group">
               <label><b>Nome da Ferramenta</b></label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{tool.name}}">
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label><b>Tag da  Ferramenta</b></label>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tag_tool" value="{{tool.tag_tool}}">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label><b>Área Responsável</b></label>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="area" value="{{tool.area}}">
                   </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <label><b>Empresa</b></label>
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control form-control-md" value="{{tool.company}}">
                         {% for company in company %}
                            <option value="{{company.name_company}}"> {{company.name_company}} </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                   </div>
           </div>
       </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><b>Tipo de Ferramenta</b></label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-md" name="type" value="{{tool.type}}">
                        <option>Manual</option>
                        <option>Eletroportátil</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label><b>Status</b></label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-md" name="status" value="{{tool.status}}">
                        <option>Ativo</option>
                        <option>Inativo</option>
                        <option>Condenada</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label><b>Imagem da Ferramenta</b></label>
                <img src="{{ tool.tool_image.url }}" class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="200" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label><b>Imagem da Tag</b></label>
                <img src="{{ tool.tag_image.url }}" class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="200"  alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <label><b></b></label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="dropzone dropzone-single">
                    <div class="fallback">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="tool_image">
                            <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="dropzone dropzone-single">
                    <div class="fallback">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="tag_image">
                            <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <label><b></b></label>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label><b>QR Code</b></label>
                <img src="{{ tool.qr_code.url }}" class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="200" alt="">
            </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
               <label><b>Observações</b></label>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <textarea class="form-control form-control-alternative" rows="7" name="observation"></textarea>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <label><b></b></label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button class="btn btn-icon btn-3 btn-primary" type="submit">
                    <span class="button-power--icon"><i class="ni ni-folder-17"></i></span>
                    <span class="btn-inner--text">Atualizar Ferramenta</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% include "includes/footer.html" %}

{% endblock content %}

<!-- Specific JS goes HERE -->
{% block javascripts %}

  <script src="/static/assets/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/assets/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.extension.js"></script>

{% endblock javascripts %}
```

VIEW QUE BUSCA OS VALORES DA TABLE COMPANY

```html
def edit_tool(request, tool_id):
    tool = get_object_or_404(Tool, pk=tool_id)

    tool_edit = {'tool': tool}

    company = Company.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'edit_tool.html', tool_edit, {'company': company})
```

[Imagem da Página](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMIJf.png)

Comment: Acredito que seu return devesse ser: `render(request, 'edit_tool.html', {'tool': tool, 'company': company})`, não?

Comment: Paulo, funcionou, agradeço demais, estou iniciando e sinto dificuldade em algumas coisas ainda... após implementar sua solução, está retornando os valores do banco no select, porém ao salvar parece que ele não consegue pegar o id, tipo quando altero e salvo, o campo aparece em branco.

Comment: Utilize um novo post para esta nova questão.